# Is it possible to exlude member fields from casting?

Tags: c++

I've been working on a data loader and saver.

The saver uses this:

```
fstream.write((char*) &Object, sizeof(Object));
```

The Object has a field which is a pointer, and I was wondering if there is a way to exlude the pointer from saving.

Thanks.

Comment: No.  If you need to serialize your object get a library that handles all the for you, like boost.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do that. Use a de-/serialization library like `boost::archive` instead to control what's serialized and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Object has a field which is a pointer, and I was wondering if there is a way to exlude the pointer from saving.

Not with the way you are using it.

If you are not in a position to use a serialization library, you can write a function that works for your specific needs.

```
namespace MyApp
{
   std::ostream& write(std::ostream& out, Object const& obj)
   {
      // Use ostream::write for the members of Object that you wish to save.
      // out.write(...);
      // out.write(...);

      return out;
   }
}
```

and then use

```
MyApp::write(fstream, obj);
```